# How can I insert a record into a table that depends on a foreign key linking to a previous table?

Tags: insert, ms-access, bulk-insert

Following on from [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/254513/what-principles-should-i-follow-when-entering-data-into-a-complex-relational-dat/254517#254517). I have a dictionary file written in XML. I've written a program in VB.NET to parse this file and store all the data in Class objects, and now I want to write a subroutine to insert all of this data into an Access database. What I'm struggling with is working out how to use SQL to `INSERT` all of the data.

There are 20 tables, and the main table is called `Entry`, which all the other tables link back to. To give a simplified example of the data structure, there is also a `Keyword` table, which links back to the `Entry`. And there is the `Keyword_Priority` table, which links back to `Keyword`. Both relationships are one-to-many, as below:

[image]

**My question**

I can use SQL `INSERT` for the `Entry` table to create one record. But how would I then create a record for the `Keyword` table, referring to the primary key of the `Entry` record I've just created? And how would I then create a record for `Keyword_Priority`, referring to the `Keyword` record? And so on.

This is all going to be done through VB.NET - I can't use Forms because there are 180,000+ entries to input. Is there any way to store a variable in SQL that I can refer to later?

Comment: Use `INSERT .. SELECT` with WHERE condition by a table which was previously inserted in using data values which were inserted.

Comment: Since you mentioned 180,000+ entries is your data source in text files tab delimited or csv files?

Comment: @Kumar - Neither, the data source is an XML file. That's why it needed to be parsed first before being inputted into a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also do it like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135437/get-last-insert-id-from-access

by making use of @@identity

```
select @@IDENTITY
```

which will return the latest created ID for the database connection

OR make use of the "inbound" property that most id-columns are simply growing int values - so

```
select max(id) from Entry
```

Comment: Oh sweet. So if I were to perform two sequential inserts, the second one just needs `select @@IDENTITY` to grab the ID from the first for the foreign key value?

Comment: yep - but I suggest you read up on the MSDN article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/ks9f57t0(v=vs.71)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: So I've tried the following statement:
`"INSERT INTO Keyword (Keyword, EntryFK) VALUES (?, (SELECT @@IDENTITY FROM Entry))"` But it throws an exception `"Query input must contain at least one table or query"`. Any idea where this has gone wrong?

Comment: And I've tried deleting the `FROM` clause so it's just `SELECT @@IDENTITY` within the `VALUES`, but that doesn't work either. This time it just says that there's a Syntax error but doesn't specify.

Comment: did you read up on the whole procedure in the linked MSDN document?

Comment: I did but didn't understand how to adapt it to my code at first glance. I had another look and managed to get the `SELECT` command for ID working, so now it seems to be working properly :). I've successfully imported data onto two tables, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```sql
INSERT INTO Entry (EntrySequence) 
VALUES ('new EntrySequence');

INSERT INTO Keyword (Keyword, EntryFK)
SELECT 'new Keyword', Entry.EntryID
FROM Entry
WHERE Entry.EntrySequence = 'new EntrySequence';

INSERT INTO Keyword_Priority (KeywordPriority, KeywordFK)
SELECT 'new KeywordPriority', Keyword.Id
FROM Keyword /* , Entry */
WHERE Keyword.Keyword = 'new Keyword'
/* AND Entry.EntrySequence = 'new EntrySequence'
   AND Entry.EntryID = Keyword.EntryFK */
```

Comment: Brilliant. Simple and looks like it should work great. Will try both yours and @eagle275's approaches and see what works. Thanks!